# When upgrade an item in WoW, does the use and proc upgrade as well?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I am considering upgrading the Darkmoon fair trinket, but I see that the UI shows only the stats will be upgraded, will the use or proc be upgraded as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it will, it just doesn't show.

Comment: @Ravekner There is nothing wrong with answering your own question.

Comment: @JamesJiao that may be so, but it seems kind of like "running a race where you are the only runner" to me. (Rewarding yourself for asking a question you already know the answer to.) You aren't actually helping someone else and your patting yourself on the back for it.

Comment: @Ravekner See this [meta] post: [Asking a question to which you already know the answer](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5670/asking-a-question-to-which-you-already-know-the-answer)

Comment: @galacticninja That's fine that you agree with that Q&A. I've already stated that I do not and I will upvote/downvote accordingly.

Comment: @Ravekner You do realize there is a button for that when posting a question right? This is a site to share knowledge, not show off.

Comment: And how are you sharing knowledge? You gave nothing as evidence to prove that your answer is correct. And giving an answer with evidence that provides verifiable proof is not showing off.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.askmrrobot.com

This site has a list of all potential gear and also shows the gear you currently have equipped on your character.

It also has a feature where you can upgrade gear and it shows the stat changes before and after the upgrade.
[image]

In this picture you can see that the Lessons of the Darkmaster Trinket has 847 Expertise and a Use that increases your strength by 4232 for 20 sec.

After upgrading it on the site, it changes to this-
[image]

It now has 913 Expertise and the use now increases your strength by 4561 for 20 sec.

This can be done with any piece of gear they have on there lists and is very helpful when trying to figure out what you may want to upgrade next.